# Identify spinlock holder

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, spinlock

Is it possible to find out who (place in code) locked a `spinlock`? Some file with statistics or so?

More info about my issue: I have a place in code which is trying to obtain a `spinlock`. The cpu core which runs the kernel thread with `spin_lock_irqsave` is 100% loaded. I turned on lockup detection in kernel. However I don't get '`BUG: spinlock lockup`'. The only info which I get in syslog is 'spinlock waiting more than 120 secs' (I get this from the other threads which are trying to access the `spinlock`, not from the 100% loaded one).

Thanks
Rene

Comment: Can you please post the full error? Normally the error looks like this: `BUG: spinlock lockup suspected on CPU#0, sh/11786 [...]`

Comment: Here you are: http://pastebin.com/gESRkFvi Thanks!

Comment: Enable `CONFIG_DEBUG_LOCKDEP`, also check what instrumentation is already provided by kernel (hint *lib/Kconfig.debug*).